# Invalid data error reading pass **********. Manifest signature did not verify successfully. Could you please tell what this error could mean?

Tags: passbook, wallet, passkit

Invalid data error reading pass **********. Manifest signature did not verify successfully. Could you please tell what this error could mean?

Comment: It means exactly what it says, your sinature didn’t match the content of the manifest, or there was some other issue with the signature E.g. using an expired certificate.   Posting your code is the only way we can help diagnose why this happened.

Comment: There are dozens of ways. I would start with the signpass tool that Apple provides with the documentation. You can then take the Objective-c source code of that app and covert it to whatever language you choose.

Comment: It could be that the manifest you are signing is incorrect. You also don’t mention the need for the private key. Both are essential for a valid signature. To debug compiling and signing a .pkpass bundle requires more than just speculation.  This is a coding site, we can help with your code, but we need to see it first.

Comment: I could tell you what is wrong, but I would not be able to tell you *why* it is wrong, without seeing your code.

Comment: Post a link in your question or a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your pass, I note the following:

```
error   14:17:17.882524 +0700   Pass Viewer Invalid data error reading pass pass.com.xxxxx.xxxxxxxxxcard/0606. Manifest signature did not verify successfully
```

Looking at your pass contents, it is obvious why the signature did not verify. The signature file is empty:

```
-rwxr-xr-x@   5685 Mar 16 14:55 icon.png
-rwxr-xr-x@   7758 Mar 16 14:55 icon@2x.png
-rwxr-xr-x@   5149 Mar 16 14:55 logo.png
-rwxr-xr-x@  10693 Mar 16 14:55 logo@2x.png
-rwxr-xr-x@    391 Mar 16 14:55 manifest.json
-rwxr-xr-x@    228 Mar 16 14:55 pass.json
-rwxr-xr-x@      0 Mar 16 14:55 signature
-rwxr-xr-x@  20388 Mar 16 14:55 strip.png
-rwxr-xr-x@  26843 Mar 16 14:55 strip@2x.png
```

The SHA hashes in the manifest check out ok, so this points to a problem with your signing code. You mentioned that you extract the private key. This could be part of your problem, since without a key, you cannot sign the pass.

But with no code, it is absolutely impossible to speculate any more than this.